# Deploying Application Insights bits to another server

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

I installed the Application Insight SDK from nugget packages and when I run the code I am able to log the telemetry data to cloud. Now I want to move these bits to my TEST server.Can I copy the bits directly to TEST server. after doing this, does the application logs the data to Azure?

I am using ASP.Net Application.I created Application Insight Resource in the cloud with the application type as ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Insights SDK libraries should be deployable using XCOPY (i.e. just copy everything along with your application) without problems. Make sure to include your ApplicationInsights.config file and any changes to the Web.Config file as well.

However, remember that if you want to capture dependency calls in an IIS application, you will need to also install Status Monitor on the Test server as well.

Comment: I believe, if you're on .net 4.6 or newer, that you don't need status monitor, they added the hooks in .net itself.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks, John!